# DropDown WPF GridView

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox, drop-down-menu, wpf-controls

How implement selectable GridView embedded in WPF ComboBox.

Comment: This is a very general question, tell us what you have tried so far, and what problems you're having?

Comment: Something like this 
http://www.designerwpf.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/clip-image00113.png

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `ToggleButton`, `Popup`, and content (`Grid`, in your case) to achieve that. What specifically are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the MS DataGrid ( http://www.codeplex.com/wpf ) or any other of the free DataGrids. The GridView is often too limited...